# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Tags: selenium, salesforce, undefined, uncaught-exception, defaultview

While executing automation scrits written n selenium using cucumber frame work iam getting the below exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
    unknown error: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
```

Previously befor spring 19 release the scripts where passed .After spring 19 scripts are failing and showing ablve exception

```
public void waitForElementToBeDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LOGGER.info("element is " +element);
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Waiting for WebElement '%s' to be displayed", element.toString().replaceAll(".*-> ", "").replace("]", "")));
    element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    Assert.assertTrue(element.isDisplayed());
}
```

Comment: Hi @delframe, can you share the error logs? At what line and what error are you exactly getting for which input?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I had similar Exception on-click event. So I used a workaround. 
I wait for element to be clickable and then trying to click on it with js.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(STORE_ADMINISTRATION_LOCATOR));
// driver.findElement(STORE_ADMINISTRATION_LOCATOR).click(); <== this line returns
// WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined 

// replaced with
WebElement element = driver.findElement(STORE_ADMINISTRATION_LOCATOR);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: It's crazy that such a simple operation requires a workaround like this, but your code worked for me. Thanks for posting this!